# Onchange value in textbox not passing in Database

Tags: php, drop-down-menu

I have this script to get the text of a dropdown

```
<script>
function streetvalue(data) {

var i = street.selectedIndex;
if (i != -1) {
document.getElementById("street2").value = street.options[i].text;
}

}
</script>
```

and here is my HTML

```
<tr>
        <td width="120" height="30" class="label"><label for="accno"><strong>Street/Alley</strong></label></td>
        <td height="30" class="content">
        <select name="street" id="street" style="width:200px;"  onchange="streetvalue(this)" required>
        <option value="" label="Select your street">Select your   street</option>
        <?php 
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM tblstreet ORDER BY lname asc";
        $result = dbQuery($sql);
        while($row = dbFetchAssoc($result)) {
        echo '<option value="'.$row['lid'].'">'.$row['lname'].'</option>';  
        }
        ?>
        </select>
        <input type="text" id="street2">
```

It's working perfectly when selecting items from dropdown, the textbox copies it. But when i hit submit and save it to my DB, the value that is always showing in my DB is "street2" and not the text that i selected in my dropdown. Am i missing something? thank you for your help!

[image]

When submit button is pressed here is my function

```
function doRegister()
{
$fname  = $_POST['firstname'];
$mname  = $_POST['middlename'];
$lname  = $_POST['lastname'];
$email  = $_POST['email'];  
$phone  = $_POST['phone'];
$cphone = $_POST['cphone'];
$dob    = $_POST['dob'];
$job_type = $_POST['intext4'];
$street2    = $_POST['street2'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO tbl_address (user_id, blknum, apartment, street,    street2, subdivision, city, zipcode, res_type, address) 
        VALUES ($insert_id, '$blknum', '$apart', '$street', 'street2',    '$subdi', '$city', '$zip', '$typeres', '$address')";
dbQuery($sql);
```

The street field is my dropdown menu and the street2 field is the copied text from the dropdown menu. Thank you!

Comment: Please include all relevant code in your question. That includes where you set the variable `street` in javascript. You can't magicly just use the value of a name attribute in javascript. We have no way of knowing if there's something going wrong in your javascript code if we can't see how you're declaring everything.

Comment: What do you see in the html form field called street2? Where is the code writing to the database?

Comment: Ive edited my question. thank you!

Comment: You are missing `$` in insert query. Replace `stree2` with `$street2` in values.

Comment: Hi @Samir, edited as advised. now my DB is not showing any values at all. maybe the problem is in my textbox(street2)?

Comment: Then, problem lies in your JavaScript. Debug it by alerting the value in `function streetvalue`.

Comment: @Samir Hi Sir. thank you for your reply im really new to this. can you tell me how? tyvm